# web site Deployment

Tags: apache

i am developing Mobile web site. I can deploy it in IIS server . Can i deploy the same in Apache server?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what language/frameworks you are using? For instance you can run PHP on both ISS and Aapche, but generally the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the technology you are using. If you are using ASP/ASP.NET then you cannot use Apache as Apache does not support ASP/ASP.NET scripting/programming languages.

On the other hand if your application does not use a server side technology (i doubt that though) then the web servers do not matter.

And if you are using a server side technology such as php or perl, you can port you application on either web servers as both of these technologies are available on either servers.

Comment: i dont know. what is serverside technology. I developed mobile aspx page. It doen't involve database or external files. Can i deploy it or not??  Please clear my doubt...

Comment: "I developed mobile aspx page"... this means you're using ASP.NET server side technology which only works with IIS. ASP.NET is not supposed to work on Apache natively but the following post claims that it can be made to work: http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx